# Google GeoCode REQUEST_DENIED with pound/number symbol

Tags: vb.net, google-maps-api-3, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use this URL:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1299+xyzwood+Dr+#428,+98765&sensor=false

**I'm using the URL with a HTTPWebRequest from VB.Net, .Net 4.**

The # symbol is causing a REQUEST_DENIED with an error that indicates the parsing probably stopped at the # symbol. The dummy link above shows the error.

I have tried to use # in place of # - didn't work. I thought this work once upon a time but maybe not.

I change the address to use "Unit 428" and FormattedAddress returns "#428"!

Looks like a bug to me. If not, what can I do to allow #428 in the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the encoded value for a URL is `%23`

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1299%20xyzwood%20Dr%20%23428%2C%2098765&sensor=false
```